# Image does not appear on Safari

Tags: image, safari

I am very new in coding so I created a simple github page :

The problem is that the image does not appear on Safari (both mobile and desktop).
Is there a way to fix this?

I have googled around but nothing seems to tell that there is a fix.
I use only alt, width, and height properties for my image.

here is my code :

```
<input type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
        <p>List down all the potential user roles for your product and categorise them.</p>
        <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/9b6374_3d81e624280340e7a162281f90e330e1~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_1393,h_572,al_c,q_90/9b6374_3d81e624280340e7a162281f90e330e1~mv2.webp" alt="persona" width="500" height="205">
        </label>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add webp support in Safari browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58487035/how-to-add-webp-support-in-safari-browser)