# Background-image - Webp, display in older Safari versions

Tags: html, css, sass, safari

I need to display my .png in `background-image` in older Safari versions and for the rest of browsers just display .webp format.

I need to do it only throught CSS and HTML. No script insluded. (@supports doesn´t support older Safari versions as well).

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well i dont know any way to do it, i had idea only with @supports, but its not supported as i said. To use <picture /> is not option as its backgound-img

Answer (score 1):

The webp format is not supported by Safari as of today, and I'm not sure if it is planned for implementation in the near future. But you can give the browser a choice whether to use webp or jpg like so.

The browsers are smart enough to download and use only the best supported image.

You can give a fallback or default img

refer this - [How to add webp support in Safari browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58487035/how-to-add-webp-support-in-safari-browser)

Comment: Well this looks like something i was looking for, sadly i will have chance to test it on IOS on monday, if it works, you have the bounty :) Thanks mate!

Comment: Hi i just tested it on Safari, sadly this option didnt work. Image still doesnt display.

Answer (score 0):

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="
    /uploads/img_small.webp 1x,
    /uploads/img_big.webp 2x" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="
    /uploads/img_small.jpg 1x, 
    /uploads/img_big.jpg 2x" type="image/jpeg">
  <img src="/uploads/img_small.jpg">
</picture>
```

The above example allows the browser to choose either a .jpeg or .webp image.

And as far as .webp goes, it is available on Safari 14

[Answer Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58487035/how-to-add-webp-support-in-safari-browser)

Comment: I needed background-img on <div>, not <img />. But thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<picture>
  <source type="image/svg+xml" srcset="stackoverflow.svg">
  <source type="image/webp" srcset="stackoverflow.webp">
  <img src="stackoverflow.png">
</picture>
```

This allows browser to reject the unsupported file types.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)

Answer (score 0):

Just for completenes sake, *image-set* is the way to set webp **background-image** with fallback:

```
.some-class {
  background-image: url('fallback-image.png');
  background-image: image-set(
    url('image.webp') 1x,
    url('image@2x.webp') 2x,
    url('fallback-image.png') 1x,
    url('fallback-image@2x.png') 2x
  );
}
```

The webkit-prefix might have to be used depending on the browser. And to this day firefox does not seem to support it. Check out [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=image-set) for more info.

**Edit:** Just tried it myself in firefox and the webkit-prefix seems to work. This just shows that one should rather trust the [official docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image/image-set) and test it yourself.