# Dealing with Safari and .webp images in 2022

Tags: css, macos, background-image, webp, browser-detection

I've been waiting to use `.webp` images for a *very* long time.

It's 2022, so, given:

- the image format has existed for a decade
- Chrome started supporting `.webp` in Jan 2014
- Firefox started supporting `.webp` in Jan 2019

I decided the day before yesterday to take the plunge and convert a bunch of `.png` images on a website to `.webp` images.

Rookie error. Because, of course, I should have checked: https://caniuse.com/webp first and that would have told me that **Safari** on anything earlier than **macOS 11.0 Big Sur (Nov 2020)** does *not* support `.webp` images.

But I'm tired of waiting. So... Safari can carry on using `.png` images I suppose.

Because I absolutely **do** want to serve `.webp` images to Firefox, Brave, Chrome, Edge, Opera etc. users.

If I were using marked up images, declaring one or more fallback images is elementary:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="a-webp-for-most-browsers.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="a-png-for-safari.png" type="image/png"> 
  <img src="a-png-for-safari.png" alt="My Image">
</picture>
```

But (sigh) in this instance, the images are CSS background images, so options for creating fallbacks are more limited:

- CSS [`image-set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image/image-set()) still has [pretty low support](https://caniuse.com/css-image-set) at present
- CSS feature queries using `@supports` do not extend to image formats.

Am I limited to browser-sniffing via PHP, like this:

```
if (preg_match('/Mac OS X/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {

  $Body_Element_CSS_Class_List .= ' oh-no-here-comes-safari';
}
```

Is there a better / more reliable approach I can adopt than browser-detection?

Comment: See one of the answers here that talks about background images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58487035/how-to-add-webp-support-in-safari-browser

Comment: Thanks, @Rob. Which answer do you mean though? VeronicaWatt's answer? I think that answer is out-of-date.

Comment: That's the one but I might have glanced too quickly as I had to leave.

Comment: @Rob - No worries. To be honest I had to read Veronica's answer 2-3 times before I could completely get my head around it. In any case, I appreciate your taking an interest in the question above. On which note... I think I may have found the solution. I am in the process of testing it now. If everything works I will write it up below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, it's hard to provide fallbacks for CSS background-images

In my question I wrote:

> If I were using **marked-up images**, declaring one or more fallback images is elementary [...]
>
> But (sigh) in this instance, the images are CSS **background-images**, so options for creating fallbacks are more limited

And for now, at least, - ie. while we're still waiting (in 2022) for widespread cross-browser support for the CSS `image-set()` function - that's true.

---

### But a marked-up `<img>` can *replace* each CSS background-image

While I was hunting around for alternative approaches, I unexpectedly came across this July 2021  comment by **Quentin Albert**:

> For what most people use background images for you can nowadays easily use *object-fit* + *object-position*.
>
> **Source:** https://css-tricks.com/using-performant-next-gen-images-in-css-with-image-set/

This was news to me. I was dimly aware of the [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) CSS property, but I'd never come across the [`object-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) CSS property at all.

But it absolutely works!!

---

### The CSS I would have used if `image-set()` had support

If `image-set()` had extensive cross-browser support, this was my intended CSS, which would enable a fallback image for Safari:

```
.my-image-1 {
  background-image: url(image-set('my-sprited-images.webp', 'my-sprited-images.png'));
  background-position: 0, 0;
}

.my-image-2 {
  background-image: url(image-set('my-sprited-images.webp', 'my-sprited-images.png'));
  background-position: -100px, 0;
}
```

---

### The HTML + CSS I can use instead (thanks to `object-position`)

Since the above isn't close to reliable, I can declare the fallback image in HTML instead and position it using `object-position`:

**HTML:**

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="my-sprited-images.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="my-sprited-images.png" type="image/png"> 
  <img class="my-image-1" src="/my-sprited-images.png" alt="My Image 1">
</picture>


<picture>
  <source srcset="my-sprited-images.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="my-sprited-images.png" type="image/png"> 
  <img class="my-image-2" src="/my-sprited-images.png" alt="My Image 2">
</picture>
```

**CSS:**

```
.my-image-1 {
  object-position: 0 0;
}

.my-image-2 {
  object-position: -100px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm having the same issue, but I believe one good way to solve it for CSS background images today would be to use [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/download?webp-setclasses&q=webp).

In that link you can make a Modernizr script build that specifically verifies for webp support in the browser. Then you just have to add the script to the `<head>` and it'll add classes to the `<html>` based on the features you're verifying. So, for instance, to load different image formats for a CSS background image you would do:

```
.webp .image {
  background-image: url('/image.webp');
}
.no-webp .image {
  background-image: url('/image.png');
}
```

Comment: In my approach to web development I try to avoid third-party dependencies as much as possible, though I agree this is a viable solution for anyone comfortable with using a third-party dependency like Modernizr.

Comment: I find this the easiest solution, also because the Modernizr script can be loaded from one's own server, even be pasted into one's own Javascript file that will/should be downloaded in the `head` section. For people who want more information about this method, I'd suggest this article: https://css-tricks.com/using-webp-images/.